# Can I use msilib or other Python libraries to extract one file from an .msi file?

Tags: python, wix, windows-installer

What I really want to do is determine whether a particular file in the MSI exists and contains a particular string.

My current idea is to run:

```
 db = msilib.OpenDatabase('c:\Temp\myfile.msi',1)
 query = "select * from File"
 view = db.OpenView(query)
 view.Execute(None)
 cur_record = view.Fetch()     # do this until I get the record I want
 print cur_record.GetString(3) # do stuff with this value
```

And then if it's there, extract all the files using

```
msiexec /a c:\Temp\myfile.msi /qn TARGETDIR=c:\foo
```

and use whatever parser to see whether my string is there. But I'm hoping a less clunky way exists.

Comment: There are less clunky ways. Are you married to Python?

Comment: For now I am married to either Python or .bat file.

Comment: What if you made a library in .NET and called it from Python?

Comment: I'm hoping for something less than 5x the verbosity of the tar and grep commands I would use in *nix.

Comment: Windows Installer databases are not zip files.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, as the docs for [`msilib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) say, "Support for reading .cab files is currently not implemented". And. more generally, the library is designed for building .msi files, not reading them. And there is nothing else in the stdlib that will do what you want.

So, there are a few possibilities:

1. Find and install another library, like [`pycabinet`](http://code.google.com/p/pycabinet/). I know nothing about this particular library; it's just the first search hit I got; you probably want to search on your own. But it claims to provide a `zipfile`-like API for CAB files, which sounds like exactly the part you're missing.
2. Use `win32com` (if you've got `pywin32`) or `ctypes` (if you're a masochist) to talk to the underlying COM interfaces and/or the classic Cabinet API (which I think is now deprecated, but still works).
3. Use IronPython instead of CPython, so you can use the simpler .NET interfaces.

Since I don't have a Windows box here, I can't test this, but here's a sketch of Christopher Painter's .NET solution written in IronPython instead of C#:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package')
from Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller import *
from Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package import *

def FindAndExtractFiles(packagePath, longFileName):
    with InstallPackage(packagePath, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly) as installPackage:
        if installPackage.FindFiles(longFileName).Count() > 0:
            installPackage.ExtractFiles()
```

Comment: In C# the using(...) blocks implicitly call .Close() and .Dispose() when the objects go out of scope. This is important to release unmanaged resources.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Well, the script is about to go away right after this code ends, and there's no unwritten data to flush… but yes, it would be better to use a `with` statement here. I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: MSI handles are unmanaged resources and nasty things have been known to happen ( even database corruption ) when they aren't closed properly.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Even with `DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly`? (I'm not asking that as a challenge to you, but rather to learn whether it really is that buggy in case I ever have to deal with it again…)

Comment: I don't want to fully commit to 100% but I *think* so.  I remember from years ago encountering situations where corruption occurred and you didn't expect it to.  Taught me to always close my handles.  Thank God for managed code, IDisposable and a well written interop library to abstract me from that these days.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Well, I don't need a 100% commitment; just knowing that there's a 90% chance (or even a 10% chance) that some library has a severely unexpected bug like this is more than enough. Anyway, I feel the same about `with` in Python… except that there's one 2.6 developer preview release of IronPython that treated foundation vs. third-party disposables differently, and for some ridiculous reason it seems like half the people on SO asking questions about IronPython are still using that ancient preview release…

Comment: Well, @Michael Urman is a c/c++ software lead on the InstallShield product so he can correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: That just means I crash more (development builds) with unclosed handles than you want to think about! The need to close is context dependent, but unless you know otherwise both now and forever, it's best to clean up.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: I agree here. I'd certainly rather put a warning on my program saying "May not work with years-old developer preview releases of IronPython 2.6" than one saying "May sporadically corrupt your MSI files even though you're only opening them for read access."

Answer (score 1):

Realize that in using Python you have to deal with the Windows Installer (COM) Automation interface.  This means you have to do all the database connections, querying and processing yourself.

If you could move to C# ( or say PowerShell ) you could leverage some higher level classes that exist in Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package;

static void FindAndExtractFiles(string packagePath, string longFileName)
{
    using (var installPackage = new InstallPackage(packagePath, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
    {
        if(installPackage.FindFiles(longFileName).Count() > 0 )
            installPackage.ExtractFiles();
    }
}
```

You could also write this as ComVisible(True) and call it from Python.

Comment: Why move to C# or PowerShell instead of just using IronPython?

Comment: I don't know anything about IronPython.  If you can add a reference to Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll and Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package.dll (both managed) and write code similar to my answer, then go for it!

Comment: It's just Python as a .NET language. You generally add references dynamically at runtime (`clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller')`) instead of adding them to a project statically as you would in C#. But, either way, the equivalent of `using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;` is just `from Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller import *`. The tutorial, or the original "welcome" article in MSDN Magazine when Microsoft took over the project 6 or 7 years ago, shows you all the details, but really, there's not much more to it than this comment.

Comment: So it's basically using reflection. Write it up as an answer.  But I wouldn't be suprised if he says he has to use Python not IronPython.

Comment: IronPython _is_ Python, just like CPython, PyPy, and Jython.

Answer (score 0):

The MSI APIs are inherently clunky, so it's only a matter of where the abstraction lies. Bear in mind that if you just need this a couple times, it may be easier to browse the cab file(s) manually in Explorer. (Files are stored by file key instead of file name).

Comment: I need to do it from within an installer, so no dice.

Comment: My clunky solution works from within an installer, even without scare quotes. You may wish to reexamine your assumptions.

Comment: No, I'm just aware of defects with your design that you are not yet aware of.